# Using 'will' or 'would'?

Tags: meaning, difference, modal-verbs

My friend said,

*"I would do it if I get the chance."*

But what will be the difference if I use *'will'* in place of *'would'* in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is very similar.

> I **will** do it if I **get** the chance.

This is simply stating that the speaker will do something in the future if the opportunity arises to do it.

> I **would** do it if I **got** the chance.

This is similar to the previous sentence, but subtly implies that the speaker doesn't reasonably expect to get the chance to do whatever it is they want to do. **if I got the chance** could be interpreted as a hypothetical, depending on context.

Comment: The original sentence is different : I **would** do it if I **get** the chance.

Comment: Yes @SandipKumarMandal but Travis is pointing out that it is incorrect and should be _got_

Comment: The original would/get sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Though *would* is the past form of *will*, it doesn't necessarily mean *the past time* : *"I would be pleased to welcome you if you visit."*